I have a problem with dropdown button in flutter
this error appear after i delete a category however it deletes from firebase:

Exception has occurred.
_AssertionError ('package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart': Failed assertion: line 948 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value
== null ||
items.where((DropdownMenuItem item) {
return item.value == value;
}).length == 1': There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: Christmass.  Either zero or 2 or more
[DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value)


this all widget:
 Widget allCat() {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: catStream,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          return snapshot.hasData
              ? Column(
                  children: [
                    DropdownButton(
                      value: selectedValue,
                      hint: Text("Choose Categorey"),
                      onChanged: (val) {
                        setState(() {
                          selectedValue = val;
                        });
                      },
                      items: [
                        for (ds in snapshot.data.docs) //2 snapshot.data.docs[0]
                          DropdownMenuItem(
                            value: ds['catName'].toString(),
                            child: Text(ds['catName']),
                          ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        await DataBaseMethods().deleteCat(ds.id);
                      },
                      child: Text("Delete Category"),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              : Container();
        });
  }


make selectedValue=null and call setState just before removing from firebase

selectedValue = val stays even if you delete from backed, But the DropdownMenuItems get update value from  stream where current selected value is missing.  You can set selectedValue=null before deleting from backend.
ElevatedButton(
   onPressed: () async {
   setState(() => selectedValue = null);
   await DataBaseMethods().deleteCat(ds.id);
   },
   child: Text("Delete Category"),
),


It worked successfully thanks
